# how to use protocbuf in ndk

Tags: android-ndk, protocol-buffers

what needs to be done so that the compiler does not complain about include in .pb.h files

I downloaded the latest version of Windows x 64. I uploaded it to drive C. I wrote it in the path. Used a protoc --cpp_out=. voice.proto, received 2 files, pb.h and pb.cc.

I get errors when compiling, on the include line in the pb.h file. #include "google/protobuf/port_def.inc" and etc.

i try different variations find_package(protobuf REQUIRED). I tried to manually register include. I even tried add_subdirectory(proto/smack), it tried to build but ended with errors in the source code of the protoc

I will be glad to receive any advice, but please do not post the first links in Google. I've tried everything I've seen and I really don't understand why it's so difficult. Maybe I'm missing something on the surface?